# cfdocument crashing on Coldfusion 9 & Mac

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to generate a simple pdf using cfdocument tag like this -

```
  <cfdocument format="PDF">
       <cfoutput>
       Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet sirloin fatback #dateformat(now(), "short")#
       </cfoutput>
   </cfdocument>
```

But for some reason, the above code causes the browser to go in loop or something and after several minutes of execution I get JRun Out of memory error.

I am using MAC OS 10.7.5 and Coldfusion 9

Any clue will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution here -

http://blog.maestropublishing.com/2012/01/19/adobe-coldfusion-9-on-mac-lion-fix-for-cfdocument-and-hanging-admin/

Just add the following two lines to jvm.config file

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.HToolkit
```